# Migration from csv problem (Incorrect string value: '\xAB Nove...')

Tags: 8, migrations

In my drupal 8 project, I'm trying to import data of a content type from a csv file, everything is well, but when I'm trying to execute the migration command `drush mim my_migration` I got the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xAB Nove...' for column 'sourceid1' at row 1 in                   [error]
/Users/brahim/Sites/news8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Statement.php:59
```

It seems like a problem of database encoding.. but I don't know what is it really, any idea about the solution?

Comment: maybe related to the source file encoding format (try with UTF-8). Check also for string issues (special characters) on the source file.

Comment: thanks @xaa for replying, how can I change/check the file encoding format?

Comment: depends of your text editor, google it. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693139/how-to-convert-csv-files-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: Thank you dude! that was exactly the solution, I changed the file to UTF-8 encoding format and re-execute the migration the content has been imported as it should. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe related to the source file encoding format (try with UTF-8). Check also for string issues (special characters) on the source file.